# How to get local and public HostName in Azure VM?

Tags: azure

In [this link](https://github.com/Netflix/ndbench/blob/47978fb18f9ed3ccd4846744c9a3036c6c8b4577/ndbench-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/ndbench/core/discovery/AWSLocalClusterDiscovery.java#L45) there is two public addresses (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname` and `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta10-data/local-hostname`) that will return public and local host name for your instance (virtual machine).
Please follow this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) to know more about `169.254.169.254` in Amazon AWS.
is there any same way for Microsoft Azure VM?

Comment: public HostName? Do you mean public dns name or your VM's host name?

Comment: I was searching for public DNS and thank you for commenting. I found the solution in next answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar service in Azure ([Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-instancemetadataservice-overview)), but it doesn't seem to provide the data you need (private and public hostname).

As a workaround, I guess you could use this service to get enough metadata in order to query the Azure RM API and get the info you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```bash
Azure_VM$ curl -H Metadata:true \
               "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02" | jq

{
  "compute": {
    "location":"westeurope",
    "name":"apibuntu",
    "offer":"UbuntuServer",
    "osType":"Linux",
    "publisher": "Canonical",
    "sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
    "version": "16.04.201611150",
    "vmId": "0dcfd4a2-c786-404a-bc08-6fdfe82e68db",
    "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2"
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.90.2.4",
              "publicIpAddress": "104.45.24.73"
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "10.90.2.0",
              "prefix": "24"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": "000D3A238014"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Docs available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-instancemetadataservice-overview).